# Trigger event after plotting of each point in OpenLayers Vector

Tags: javascript, dom-events, openlayers

I am quite new to dealing with OpenLayers. When drawing a Polygon or LineString vector, how can I trigger events after plotting each point. For example, I want to show popups or tooltips to assist the user in between each point. How could I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `point` callback function. It is called after each point is drawn on the map.

```
var drawOptions = {
    callbacks : {
        "point": pointHandler
    },
};
var drawControls = {
    line: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(lineLayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Path, drawOptions)
};

var pointHandler = function(point) {
    console.log(point.toString());
}
```